# I will talk to you vs I will talk with you?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct ?

> I will talk to you tomorrow

or

> I will talk with you tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, and would normally be understood to mean the same thing. "talk to you" is more common.

Answer (score 1):

Either would be correct in that context.

---

In a context of *stress*, then the nuances become more important -- if someone talks *to* you about a problem, it implies they are doing the talking and you are doing the listening and they're kind of giving you orders about it. If someone talks *with* you about a problem, then you are having a dialogue where both of you are trying to understand and solve the problem.

Those nuances generally show up only in contexts of Stress In a Relationship.